# FuelPHP Cache visibility between task & app controller

Tags: caching, task, fuelphp

I use memcache as cache driver and I noticed that my app does not see \Cache::set('key', $value); saved in the task. When I try to read it from the app controller level the \Cache::get('key') is not set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memcache cache driver available in the FuelPHP framework.

If you mean "memcached" (which is not the same), then assuming your config is ok and both the webserver and the commandline use the same config, that should work without problems.